# Getting live height of html with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, variables, live

How can I get a live variable of the html element in JQuery?

So far I have been using this,

```
var htmlHeight = $('html').height();
```

This has worked fine, but I have recently added some slideToggle divs into my webpage which add a lot of extra height to my document, and the current variable is out by quite a lot if the slideToggle divs are active.

I have tried to add a live event to it but it fails as I just need the variable and do not need to bind it to anything such as click or hover.

Comment: "How" are the slide Toggle divs added 'into' the webpage?

Comment: They are hidden in the css and just called upon by a click handler in jquery like $('#someID').click(function() { $('#someID2').slideToggle(); }); If this helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why dont you use a function to get the height each time its needed with your jquery

```
function curHeight(){
   return $('html').height();
}
```

so whenever you want the height of the html just call the function and it should give you the current height of the html document.

Comment: Ok this seems better than setting an timeout interval, I will try this. Thanks